# How to get email contents using EWS/MAPI for nodejs

Tags: javascript, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, node-ews

Using this node-ews package, I can send email, but I haven't been able to find a good example of how to read mails from the Inbox folder and get the email's text and attachments.

I've read the Microsoft documentation, such as this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-work-with-exchange-mailbox-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange#get-an-item-by-using-the-ews-managed-api, but the examples are in C#, C++, or VB.

However, I would like to use Nodejs for this.

Answer (score 1):

**I have found a best way extract every content using mailparser. **see bellow**

// At first Read emails from Inbox

```
const EWS = require('node-ews');
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;
// exchange server connection info
const ewsConfig = {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  host: 'hostname'
};
const options = {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  strictSSL: false
};
// initialize node-ews
const ews = new EWS(ewsConfig, options);
var ewsFunction = 'FindItem';
    var ewsArgs = {
        'attributes': {
            'Traversal': 'Shallow'
        },
        'ItemShape': {
            't:BaseShape': 'Default'
        },
        'ParentFolderIds' : {
            'DistinguishedFolderId': {
            'attributes': {
                'Id': 'inbox'
            }
          }
        }
    };
    // Itreate over all the emails and store Id and ChangeKey.
    ews.run(ewsFunction, ewsArgs, ewsSoapHeader)
    .then(result => {
        // Iterate over the result and extract Id and ChangeKey of the messages and pass those to GetItem function to read messages
    })
```

// For reading individual messages returned by FindItem (using Id and ChangeKey)

```
var ewsFunction = 'GetItem';
      var ewsArgs = {
        'ItemShape': {
          'BaseShape': 'Default',
          'AdditionalProperties': {
            'FieldURI': [
              { 'attributes': { 'FieldURI': 'item:MimeContent'}}
            ]
          }
        },
        'ItemIds': {
          'ItemId': {
            'attributes': {
              'Id': Id,
              'ChangeKey': ChangeKey
            }
          }
        }
      };
      await ews.run(ewsFunction, ewsArgs, ewsSoapHeader)
      .then(result => {
          // Iterate over the result and extract meesage
          const {Message} = result.ResponseMessages.GetItemResponseMessage.Items
          let mimeContent = Buffer.from(Message.MimeContent['$value'], 'base64').toString('binary');// decode mime content
          simpleParser(mimeContent).then(async function (mail) {
            console.log("mail")
            console.log(mail.attachments)
            console.log(mail.headers.get('message-id'))
            console.log(mail.headers.get('references'))
            console.log(mail.headers.get('in-reply-to'))
            console.log({
              // text: mail.text,
              // html: mail.html ? mail.html.replace(/<meta([^>]+)>/g, "") : "",
              from: (mail.from) ? mail.from.value.map(item => item.address) : [],
              to: (mail.to) ? mail.to.value.map(item => item.address) : [],
              cc: (mail.cc) ? mail.cc.value.map(item => item.address) : [],
              bcc: (mail.bcc) ? mail.bcc.value.map(item => item.address) : [],
              messageId: mail.messageId,
              subject: mail.subject
            })
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log("err")
            console.log(err)
          })
      })
```

Here you will get the full parsed mail contents with attachments. Happy Coding!!!